# MPAndroidChart set a fixed markerview

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have created a chart using `MPAndroidChart` and I am looking to see if it is possible to set a fixed position for the `markerview`. My chart is being used inside a `fragment`. I want the `markerview` to always stay at the top of chart in the center of the `X-Axis`. I am using the `Override Draw` method but I can not get it to sit in the position I want it unless I specify it with `ints`. I tried to follow another guide where I override the `getXoffset()` but it I can not use this method in my class. Is this possible to do?

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posX, float posY) {
posX = 400;
posY = -30;

canvas.translate(posX,posY);
draw(canvas);
canvas.translate(-posX,-posY);
}
}
```

**Full Fragment Code**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.graph1_fragment, container, false);

mChart = (LineChart) view.findViewById(R.id.chart1);
mChart.setNoDataText("Getting Data From Server");
mChart.setNoDataTextColor(Color.BLACK);
makeChart();

return view;
}

private void makeChart() {

StringRequest req = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    jsonResponse = "";
                    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("Data");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject o = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        time = o.getString("time");
                        open = o.getString("close");

                        float val = Float.parseFloat(open);

                        yVals1.add(new Entry(i, val));

                        long unixSeconds = Long.parseLong(time);
                        Date date = new Date(unixSeconds * 1000L);
                         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new 
 SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM");

 sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
                        String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);

                        xValues.add(formattedDate);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
    }
});

Graph_AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setGridBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(true);
        mChart.setDrawBorders(true);

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setEnabled(false);

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);
        xAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new DefaultAxisValueFormatter(0) {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return xValues.get((int) value % xValues.size());
            }

            @Override
            public int getDecimalDigits() {
                return 0;
            }
        });

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        leftAxis.setDrawAxisLine(true);
        leftAxis.setDrawZeroLine(false);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setGridColor(Color.WHITE);
        leftAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.BLACK);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
        LineDataSet set1;


        set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals1, "DataSet 1");

        set1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        set1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        set1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        set1.setDrawCircles(true);
        set1.setLineWidth(3f);
        set1.setCircleRadius(1f);
        set1.setCircleColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        set1.setFillAlpha(50);
        set1.setDrawFilled(true);
        set1.setFillColor(Color.parseColor("#008000"));
        set1.setHighLightColor(Color.rgb(244, 117, 117));
        set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);

        dataSets.add(set1);

        LineData datab = new LineData(dataSets);
        datab.setDrawValues(false);

        mChart.setData(datab);
        mChart.setDrawMarkers(true);
        IMarker marker = new 
  YourMarkerView(getContext(),R.layout.custom_marker);
        mChart.setMarker(marker);

    }
}, 3000);
}
public class YourMarkerView extends MarkerView {

private TextView tvContent;

public YourMarkerView(Context context, int layoutResource) {
    super(context, layoutResource);

    // find your layout components
    tvContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
}

// callbacks everytime the MarkerView is redrawn, can be used to update the
// content (user-interface)
@Override
public void refreshContent(Entry e, Highlight highlight) {

    tvContent.setText("$" + e.getY());

    // this will perform necessary layouting
    super.refreshContent(e, highlight);
}

private MPPointF mOffset;

@Override
public MPPointF getOffset() {

    if(mOffset == null) {
        // center the marker horizontally and vertically
        mOffset = new MPPointF(-(getWidth() / 2), -getHeight());
    }

    return mOffset;
}


@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas, float posX, float posY) {
    posX = 400;
    posY = -30;

    canvas.translate(posX,posY);
    draw(canvas);
    canvas.translate(-posX,-posY);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use this :

```
posX=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*ratio1
posY=Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*ratio2
```

`Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics()` will give you the sizes of your screen and then you can choose any ratio you want in order to set the position.